# Import Data from 3 MDBs and 1 CSV, use in DataGrid object

Tags: database, vb.net

This is eventually to be run on a primitive Windows environment for a PLC, so I'm using Visual Basic .NET 4.0 in Studio 2013.

Anyways here's the challenge I expect to be fairly simple once get going: I've got 3 MDBs with 1 table each and 1 CSV file, which I need to import data from and provide various viewing/editing functionality.

These MDBs are essentially a list of parameters for various "program settings" run by the PLC, called "recipes". There are over 200 parameters, but for some reason they were limited to 100 per file, so they had to create 3 MDBs. But they're essentially representing one long list of parameters. So for instance, the PLC might execute 4 different formats, or recipes, each with a unique "IndexName" key. So in the first MDB, the table has 4 rows and 106 columns, and in the second one 4 rows and 110 columns.

[Here's a screenshot of the table in Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdmBk.png)

"Export Demo.zip" on this post
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?719287-RESOLVED-mdb-database-to-csv-file
seemed rather promising, but it's in VB6 and it's a bit beyond me to adapt to my environment.

I can create one DataSource/DataSet per source MDB/CSV, but my objective is to populate a single DataGrid object with Data from all those sources. I'm currently looking into how I can consolidate the data into one DataTable.

Comment: Not much detail - are the MDBs similar? identical structure? Not at all alike? The data could be merged into one datatable - *how* depends on what happens with dupes and maybe those Missing Details. VIewing in a `DataGridView` is trivial and exporting to CSV *can* be.

Comment: Hi Plutonix. Many thanks for taking the time to edit and reply. I've added some details about the MDBs. I'm currently looking into how to merge the data into a datatable as you suggested. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pulling a few bits and pieces from various sources together, I managed to get this working. Particularly useful was the DataTable.Merge function, took me a while to find that.

Not sure how useful this code might be for others, or if it goes against stackoverflow etiquette. I'm happy to fix accordingly, but I did want to share that I managed.

Obviously this isn't the complete code, but hopefully the most relevant bits. I'm happy to provide some more pieces if required. Code comments/improvements welcome, I'm just a beginner!

```
Sub LoadDataIntoDataGrid()
    'Loads CSV Table, Transpose & Load 3 MDB tables, Capture each Table Params, & Merge all 3 into 1
    'Adjusts the merged table according to the csv file

    Dim CSVTable As DataTable, MDB0Table As DataTable, MDB1Table As DataTable, MDB2Table As DataTable, _
        CRLTable As DataTable
    Dim CSVRow As DataRow
    Dim removeRows As New List(Of String)

    'Populate CSV Table
    CSVTable = ReadFromCSV("CSVFile.csv")
    'Populate 3 MDB tables with transposed Data: Rows are parameters
    MDB0Table = ReadFromMDB("First.mdb", "SELECT * from Table1")
    MDB1Table = ReadFromMDB("Second.mdb", "SELECT * from Table2")
    MDB2Table = ReadFromMDB("Third.mdb", "SELECT * from Table3")
    'Put each Parameter name into MDBTableParams
    For Each ParamName In MDB0Table.Rows
        CRLForm.MDBTableParams(0).Add(ParamName(0))
    Next
    For Each ParamName In MDB1Table.Rows
        CRLForm.MDBTableParams(1).Add(ParamName(0))
    Next
    For Each ParamName In MDB2Table.Rows
        CRLForm.MDBTableParams(2).Add(ParamName(0))
    Next
    'Set Primary Keys
    MDB0Table.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {MDB0Table.Columns("NamePar")}
    MDB1Table.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {MDB1Table.Columns("NamePar")}
    MDB2Table.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {MDB2Table.Columns("NamePar")}
    CSVTable.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {CSVTable.Columns("NamePar")}

    'Merge all 3 MDB Tables into 1
    CRLTable = MDB0Table
    CRLTable.Merge(MDB1Table)
    CRLTable.Merge(MDB2Table)

    'For each row in the merged table, either mark for removal or add the description from the CSV file
    CRLTable.Columns.Add("Desc", GetType(String))
    CRLTable.Columns("Desc").SetOrdinal(1) 'Make Description second column (after "NamePar")
    For Each CRLRow In CRLTable.Rows
        CSVRow = CSVTable.Rows.Find(CRLRow("NamePar"))
        If CSVRow Is Nothing Then
            removeRows.Add(CRLRow("NamePar")) 'tag rows to be removed due to missing in CSV
        Else
            CRLRow("Desc") = CSVRow("DESC_" & CRLForm.ComboBoxLanguage.Text)
        End If
    Next

    'Remove Rows tagged for removal due to absence from CSV file
    For Each row In removeRows
        CRLTable.Rows.Remove(CRLTable.Rows.Find(row))
    Next

    'Set DataGridView data source as the cleaned merged table 
    CRLForm.DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect ' Otherwise DataSource = CRLTable refuses to populate
    CRLForm.DataGridView1.DataSource = CRLTable
    CRLForm.DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.ColumnHeaderSelect
End Sub
```